# Access the phone internal storage to push in SQLite database file

Tags: android

I am developing my android application using Netbeans and java. When I am using the emulator I can access the File explorer and insert an SQLite database in to device internal memory by accessing the following path, `data/data/com.example.helloandroid/database`

But I can not access this location to push the SQLite File in to the phone's internal storage (location) when I am using the real device.

Can someone please help me how to add the file in to phones internal storage. Thanks

Comment: cant you keep the database file in assets folder and copy to document folder programmatically?

Comment: I can simply push in the database file when using the emulator, With the DDMS -> File explorer. I need To do the same way when using the real device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the device doesn't have root permission, that's why you can't access it. If you want to do in your app with programmatically then it is possible. If anybody knows better then this please share it.

**EDIT:** ok, first of all,

```
1. copy your Database.db file in your projects assets folder.
2. now using code copy database file from /asset to device's internal storage 
   (data/data/<package name>/database folder).
```

For copy file use below code,

```
try {
     // Open your local db as the input stream
     InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("your database file name");

     // Path to the just created empty db
     String outFileName = "/data/data/<your_app_package_name>/databases/<database_file_name>";

     OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

     // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int length;
     while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) 
         {
       myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
     Log.e("error", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: can you please explain, how to move a sqlite database file in to phones internal memory programatically.

Comment: for what reason you want to do that? for your application?

Comment: I have created a SQLite database with many records.(Reading some xml files). So this complete application works with the SQLite database records. I need to test it with the real device and stucked..!!!!

Comment: Its all ok, But please clarify you are working on your application and you are using this database. and now your are testing it on real device, M I right?

Comment: It Works when using the emulator. Can go to DDMS-> File Explorer and push in. But when use real devide not

Comment: please please, explain in brief, I m thinking you are working on one app with eclipse ide and you have a ready sqlite database which one you are using in your app by putting it in file/file/package name/database folder? right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That was i was doing. But when I need to push in the database file into real device problem occured. What u think is correct

Comment: Yes user370305. That was exactly I wanted. Thank you soooo much. Thanks again for your time and the help. really appreciate.

Comment: It works on most devices but for some device it doesnt .Have got any idea about this.?

Comment: @Abhilash - What types of problem are you facing?

Comment: @Abhilash - Instead of hard coded path `/data/data/` use `public abstract File getDatabasePath (String name)` method.

Comment: I got it now,I used 'File dirFile = this.getDir("dummydb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);'  and 'String outFileName =  dirFile.getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + dbname;'