# how to insert database at runtime of activity?

Tags: java, android, database

I've completed developing the first phase of my application. I wanted to **test** it on an **actual device** so hooked up my mobile to my computer and **installed** the application. This application uses a **database**, so when I run my app on my mobile it throws an **error**

```
W/System.err(21912): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: UserTable: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE username='null'
```

How can I insert my database into my device during runtime ?

Regular method of inserting it through Eclipse wont work as root access is blocked by the mobile phone.

Comment: Got my answer.
Refer to the link


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268908/access-the-phone-internal-storage-to-push-in-sqlite-database-file

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class _DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(strCREATE_TABLE1);
                InitTables(db);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        private void InitTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("colName", "...");
            //..
            db.insert("MyTable", "id", cv);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This looks promising !! Trying it now.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this guide :

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

For creating new table you have to write the code in `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)` method and then in

```
onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion) pass the new version.
```

Comment: I am not creating a new table, or creating a new database. I already have a database that I must insert into my testing device.

Comment: Is your device attached with PC? If yes then please detach it and then try because your device memory is used by PC.