# How to push a file on a phone running Android 4.0.3?

Tags: android, emulation, push

I've created an app on Android 2.2 and used emulator to to test the app. Also the app needs two files to be pushed, file `A.xml` onto `data/data/com.android.myApp/files/A.xml` and a sqlite database `B.db` onto `data/data/com.android.myApp/databases/B.db`.

Now I'm trying to test the app on a Galaxy S2 running Android 4.0.3 where I can't find any of  those familiar folders. There are four folders: `data`, `mnt`, `system`, `tmp`. The `data` folder is empty and to add to my problem I can't find my application on the File explorer.

How can I find my app and push these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have read permission on data folder.

you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268908/access-the-phone-internal-storage-to-push-in-sqlite-database-file)

First, put A.xml and B.db to assets folder

then open by

```
InputStream is = c.getAssets().open("A.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

The folder structure is no different than on earlier emulator versions. It might be that you need to be root in order to be allowed to list the contents of the `/data` directory.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot see the contents of the /data directory of an actual device due to security reasons. Maybe you could use the PackageManager to seek more details on the packages installed.