# how to use backup database in android programming

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have been developing android application using SQLite database.
Unfortunately all content of my database got deleted by me. 
but I have a database backup.
is there any possible ways to use my database?

Comment: you can replace that db to ur current db

Comment: please explain how to replace db

Comment: copy your database to data/data/your packagename/databases/ ,when your application start

Comment: how to use copied database again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two ways is there

1) [Access the phone internal storage to push in SQLite database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268908/access-the-phone-internal-storage-to-push-in-sqlite-database-file)

2)[sqlite-database-on-your-android-emulator](http://www.boringmonday.com/jc/2010/11/22/sqlite-database-on-your-android-emulator/)