# where to place/push my .sql file (sqlite) to my android device?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, push

I know that when i run in an emulator, the db file can be viewed, pushed and pulled at data/data/com.appname/databases/db.sql

but that is using emulator, what if i run using an android phone? how do i push the db file? 
please help me by providing clear tutorial! thanks in advance!

I have been reading answers from existing similar question like this:

[Access the phone internal storage to push in SQLite database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268908/access-the-phone-internal-storage-to-push-in-sqlite-database-file)

but I dont understand how to do it. where to put the code and etc and also when I launch my app, it will be able to access the database file and retrieve the data to display them in my apps

Comment: You should place in assets and access it on the first time you open the app, ../databases/.. via code... 
possible duplicate of [How to ship an Android application with a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Comment: @VenomVendor I did try the code provided in the https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper 
but when creating the class    
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper{...}
it says that cannot resolve symbol 'SQLiteAssetHelper' and it is red in color. and fyi, I am using  Android studio

Comment: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/readystatesoftware/sqliteasset have you imported this library, if not import it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `.sqlite` (not `.sql`), you should take out the extension of the file and then paste it in the `assets` folder of your project.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database) question. It goes with all the specifics of how to read an already built database in your app.

But in summary, you have to create your own `class` (DataBaseHelper) that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` to read or create the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon a way of importing the database file say if we already have an existing db file (don't have to recreate it). And this tutorial helped me a lot!!!

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/